# How to customize the css of FileGator app

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm using a [FileGator](https://filegator.io/) for displaying the data in the browser.
it was built with Vue.js for frontend.

But I'm not able to customize all the CSS of the app even though I added customized CSS in the app.css in the dist folder. Hope someone gives me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Folder `dist/` is where compiled css and js are placed. If you're using npm build process as explained here https://docs.filegator.io/development.html dist folder will be overwritten each time npm build is triggered.

If you don't want to build with npm then you can use provided `configuration.php` file to add a simple style:

```
'add_to_head' => '<style>body{background:red}</style>',
```

or your own css file:

```
'add_to_head' => '<link href="/somewhere/your.css" rel=stylesheet>',
```